# How to navigate to another stack's screen while using deep linking in react-navigation v5?

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

In this case, a screen may be opened through deep linking. There's a `<BackButton />` component and I wish the button's behavior like this:

- if this screen was opened by `navigator.navigate`, then go back.
- if this screen was opened by deep-linking, then go to the Home screen.

The navigator struct like this

- Root (stack navigator)

  - Tab (bottom tab navigator)

    - Home
    - Personal
  - Main (stack navigator)

    - Store

In the begining, I wrote code like this:

```js
const onBackButtonPress = useCallback(() => {
  if (navigation.canGoBack()) {
    navigation.goBack()
  } else {
    navigation.navigate('Tab', { screen: 'Home' })
  }
), [navigation])
```

This code works, however using `navigation.navigate()` function cause a push effect (new screen comes from the right edge), not go back (new screen comes from the left edge).

Then I tried to use `navigation.replace()` and `navigation.reset()`

```js
navigation.reset({
  index: 0,
  routes: [{ name: 'Tab', state: { routes: [{ name: 'Home' }, { name: 'Personal' }] } }],
})
```

And the navigator seems couldn't handle this route (I think this is because we're in the `Main` stack now, and it couldn't handle the params).

What can I do to correct the behavior of navigation?

Answer (score 1):

> And the navigator seems couldn't handle this route (I think this is because we're in the Main stack now, and it couldn't handle the params).

Maybe unlike `navigate`, in this case, `navigation` cannot handle this route when using `replace` and `reset`, so I try to use its parent navigator and it is just exactly the behavior I've wanted!

```js
const onBackButtonPress = useCallback(() => {
  if (navigation.canGoBack()) {
    navigation.goBack()
  } else {
    const parentNaigator = navigation.dangerouslyGetParent()
    parentNaigator?.replace('Tab', { screen: 'Home' })
  }
), [navigation])
```

According to [official document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/nesting-navigators.html#navigation-actions-are-handled-by-current-navigator-and-bubble-up-if-couldnt-be-handled), navigation actions are intended to handled by current navigator and bubble up if couldn't be handled. Maybe it is a bug of `replace` and `reset`.